# paste not running from script but working on command line

Tags: bash, paste

I'm running this one liner as part of a larger script-

```
paste -d '' <(cut -c"1-5" file1) <(cut -c"1-2" file2) <(cut -c"8-" file1)
```

This takes the first 5 characters of the first file `file1`, the characters 1-2 of `file2` and then the characters 8 onwards of `file1` and pastes them all together.

```
$cat file1
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890

$cat file2
abcdefghij
abcdefghij
abcdefghij
abcdefghij
abcdefghij

output-
12345ab890
12345ab890
12345ab890
12345ab890
12345ab890
```

This works perfectly as expected from the command line (output shown above).

However if I put that line into a script (shown here)-

```
$cat a.sh

#!/bin/bash
paste -d '' <(cut -c"1-5" a) <(cut -c"1-2" b) <(cut -c"8-" a)
```

If I run the script I get this error-

```
$sh a.sh
a.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
a.sh: line 2: `paste -d '' <(cut -c"1-5" a) <(cut -c"1-2" b) <(cut -c"8-" a)'
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here? I ran it through shellcheck and it told me the script was fine.

Comment: You run your script with `sh`, and `sh` doesn't know about process substitution (the `<()` syntax). Run it with either `bash a.sh`, or make it executable (`chmod +x a.sh`) and run it with `./a.sh`. Also, the first line of `a.sh` should not be empty, or the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) could be ignored.

Comment: As an aside, your prose description doesn't agree with the code at all.  For example, where you have `cut -c1-2` your description says you want characters 3-10.

Comment: @tripleee, that's what I get for first using a real example from my work and then trying to make it simpler for the question. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run as below;

```
./a.sh
```

or

```
bash a.sh
```

bash and sh are two different shells.  bash is with more features and better syntax.